# DHCP lease renewal fails on AWS lightsail server

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, aws, cloud-init

Tuesday the 12th of September 2021 out of the blue a root server of mine running debian hosted in AWS Lightsail crashed. After a reboot it would run fine for approximately 20-60 minutes, after that it would crash again. As it turned out the server was still running but it had lost all network connections. Since AWS Lightsail does not have a serial console and only supports SSH for server administration this means the only method of regaining access to it after a crash was a reboot.

An analysis of the syslog and other logs didn't reveal any relevant clues. Also no relevant packages were installed/removed in the last days.

Because I already had issues with dhcp in the past on that server I suspected that the issue might be related to the dhcp lease renewal. So I did run some diagnostic with dhclient and it turned out that dhcp was indeed the issue that caused the server to crash. The AWS dhcp server gives very short lease times of ~20-60 minutes and as soon as the lease runs out the server will loose all networking.

I was able to create a workaround by running `dhclient -d` in an endless loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
    bash -c 'dhclient -d 2>&1 | tee -a /var/log/dhclient.log' &
    sleep 60
    kill $(jobs -p) 2>/dev/null || true
    kill -9 $(jobs -p) 2>/dev/null || true
done
```

I just run that script in a screen session and just let it run. This successfully kept the server from crashing. However this is just a dirty workaround and the real reasons for this issue still hadn't been found.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it turns out that the issue was related to IPv6.

The issue was that the networking service didn't properly run. The networking service is a oneshot script that is supposed to configure networking after boot.

`systemctl status networking` showed the following:

```
Oct 16 11:01:32 ip-172-26-9-21 dhclient[573]: DHCPACK of 172.26.9.21 from 172.26.0.1
Oct 16 11:01:32 ip-172-26-9-21 ifup[366]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 16 11:01:32 ip-172-26-9-21 dhclient[573]: bound to 172.26.9.21 -- renewal in 1374 seconds.
Oct 16 11:01:32 ip-172-26-9-21 ifup[366]: bound to 172.26.9.21 -- renewal in 1374 seconds.
Oct 16 11:01:38 ip-172-26-9-21 ifup[366]: Could not get a link-local address
Oct 16 11:01:38 ip-172-26-9-21 ifup[366]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/cloud_inet6 exited with return code 1
Oct 16 11:01:38 ip-172-26-9-21 ifup[366]: ifup: failed to bring up eth0
Oct 16 11:01:38 ip-172-26-9-21 systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 16 11:01:38 ip-172-26-9-21 systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 16 11:01:38 ip-172-26-9-21 systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.
```

As the output shows the script `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/cloud_inet6`, which is supposed to setup ipv6 via dhcp, failed to run properly.

I had IPv6 support disabled in the aws Lightsail console and in debian:

```
echo 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1' > /etc/sysctl.d/70-disable-ipv6.conf
sysctl -p -f /etc/sysctl.d/70-disable-ipv6.conf
```

Since I didn't want IPv6 support I disabled the ipv6 could init script by removing it from `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/`:

```
mv /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/cloud_inet6 ~/
```

After rebooting the server, the networking service now runs fine and the server isn't crashing anymore.

I'm still confused as to why this suddenly became an issue. As far as I can tell the cloud init script has been there since April. I can only assume since IPv6 support is pretty [new](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/01/amazon-lightsail-supports-ipv6/) in AWS Lightsail the issue was triggered by some change in the AWS infrastructure.

This issue for cloud-init in launchpad seems to document the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1863773.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently I had a very similar issue on yet another server. This time another hoster tough. The server would loose its connect after the dhcp release run out just like on the AWS server. And the networking service was in status failed too. The reason was also related to ipv6.

In the log file the message the error message "RTNETLINK answers: File exists" appeared and apparently the networking failed after trying to set the ipv6 address.

To fix the issue I had to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file. Where I replaced:

```
post-up ip -6 route add fe80::1 dev eth0
post-up ip -6 route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0
post-down ip -6 route del default via fe80::1 dev eth0
post-down ip -6 route del fe80::1 dev eth0
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
        netmask 64
```

with:

```
iface eth0 inet6 static
        address XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX
        netmask 64
        post-up sleep 5; ip -6 route add fe80::1 dev eth0
        post-up sleep 5; ip -6 route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0
        post-down sleep 5; ip -6 route del default via fe80::1 dev eth0
        post-down sleep 5; ip -6 route del fe80::1 dev eth0
```

Adding the sleep 5 seems to have done the trick.